# Mail::fake Laravel unit tests are not working, real controller works

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I would like to test if RegistrationUser mailable in Laravel 5.6 can send to selected email address.

I created RegistrationUser class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RegistrationUser extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.registration.user');
    }
}
```

After that I created EmailTest class:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Mail\RegistrationUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class EmailTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        Mail::fake();
        // Assert a message was sent to the given users...
        Mail::assertSent(RegistrationUser::class, function ($mail)  {
            return $mail->hasTo('test@o2.pl');
        });
    }
}
```

When I run PHPUnit I get this error:

```
PHPUnit 7.0.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F..                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 143 ms, Memory: 18.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\EmailTest::testExample
The expected [App\Mail\RegistrationUser] mailable was not sent.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/Users/mateusz/Sites/fifa/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/MailFake.php:41
/Users/mateusz/Sites/fifa/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:221
/Users/mateusz/Sites/fifa/backend/tests/Feature/EmailTest.php:24

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

Sending an email with the actual controller works and delivers the email message.

I don't know why this test code reports a failure.

Comment: I'm not sure I see anything that actually sends an email within your code

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the message you're sending.

Add the following inside your `assertSent`

```
$mail->build();
```

So that it is now this:

```
Mail::assertSent(RegistrationUser::class, function ($mail)  {
    $mail->build();

    return $mail->hasTo('test@example.com');
});
```